# how to modify the position caption with subcaption pack?

Tags: captions, subcaption

How to vertical modify the caption?

[image]

The code is

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-blur}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue}
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink}
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green}
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur}

\definecolor{azultenue}{RGB}{65,170,193}
\definecolor{rojotenue}{RGB}{192,2,3}
\definecolor{naranjatenue}{RGB}{241,101,35}
\definecolor{verdetenue}{RGB}{144,169,61}
\definecolor{gris135}{RGB}{135,135,135}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
{


\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm,nodesep=0.12cm}
%
\def\pscolhookii{\hskip 1cm}
\def\pscolhookiii{\hskip 1cm}
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2.2, colsep=5.2]% defines the distance between two frames
 [name=Inicio] 
 \psframegray(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
%
 \rput(0,1.5){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=azultenue]{p1}{\textcolor{black}{$p_1$}}}
%
 \rput(-1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c1}{\textcolor{black}{$c_1$}}}
 \rput(-0.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c2}{\textcolor{black}{$c_2$}}}
%
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.1,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.4,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.7,-1)
%
 \rput(1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{cl}{\textcolor{black}{$c_\lambda$}}}
%
 \ncline[arcangle=0]{->}{p1}{c1}
 \nbput[nrot=:U,labelsep=0.075cm]{\small{$ \omega_{mut}$}}
%
 \ncline[arcangle=0]{->}{p1}{c2}
 \nbput[nrot=:U,labelsep=0.075cm]{\small{$ \omega_{mut}$} }
%
 \ncline[arcangle=0]{->}{p1}{cl}
 \nbput[nrot=:U,labelsep=0.075cm]{\small{$ \omega_{mut}$} }
\rput(0,-1.8){$\bullet$ Crear $\lambda$ mutantes de $p_1$}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
&[name=Conjunto]
\psframegray(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
\pstriangle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gris135,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red,linewidth=0.06cm,linearc=0.4](0,-1.56)(5.0,4.2)
%
 \rput(0,1.5){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=azultenue]{p1}{\textcolor{black}{$p_1$}}}
%
 \rput(-1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c1}{\textcolor{black}{$c_1$}}}
 \rput(-0.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c2}{\textcolor{black}{$c_2$}}}
%
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.1,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.4,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.7,-1)
%
 \rput(1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{cl}{\textcolor{black}{$c_\lambda$}}}

\rput(0,-1.8){$\bullet$ Evaluar Padres e Hijos}
\rput(0,-2.2){$\bullet$ Elegir el más apto del conjunto}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
&[name=EM]
\psframegray(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
%
 \rput(0,0){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=verdetenue]{pnuevo}{\textcolor{black}{\hspace{0.36cm}}}}
%
\rput(0,-1.8){$\bullet$ El individuo elegido}
\rput(0,-2.3){ sustituirá a $p_1$}
\end{psmatrix}
\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, arrows=->, nodesep=4pt,  linearc=0.25, angleB=180, shortput=nab, npos = 0.4,nodesep=2.6cm}
\ncline{Inicio}{Conjunto}
\ncline{Conjunto}{EM}

}
\caption{\vspace{4.5cm}Esquema $(1+\lambda)$}\label{1maslambda-ilustracion}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cell contents doesn't have any height in your example. You should put every cell content in a single pspicture environment with the specific dimension.

The adjusting is yours ;-)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-blur}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue}
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink}
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green}
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur}

\definecolor{azultenue}{RGB}{65,170,193}
\definecolor{rojotenue}{RGB}{192,2,3}
\definecolor{naranjatenue}{RGB}{241,101,35}
\definecolor{verdetenue}{RGB}{144,169,61}
\definecolor{gris135}{RGB}{135,135,135}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm,nodesep=0.12cm}
%
\def\pscolhookii{\hskip 1cm}
\def\pscolhookiii{\hskip 1cm}
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.2, colsep=0.2]% defines the distance between two frames
 [name=Inicio] 
\begin{pspicture}[shift=-2.5](-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
 \psframegray(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
%
 \rput(0,1.5){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=azultenue]{p1}{\textcolor{black}{$p_1$}}}
%
 \rput(-1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c1}{\textcolor{black}{$c_1$}}}
 \rput(-0.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c2}{\textcolor{black}{$c_2$}}}
%
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.1,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.4,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.7,-1)
%
 \rput(1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{cl}{\textcolor{black}{$c_\lambda$}}}
%
 \ncline[arcangle=0]{->}{p1}{c1}
 \nbput[nrot=:U,labelsep=0.075cm]{\small{$ \omega_{mut}$}}
%
 \ncline[arcangle=0]{->}{p1}{c2}
 \nbput[nrot=:U,labelsep=0.075cm]{\small{$ \omega_{mut}$} }
%
 \ncline[arcangle=0]{->}{p1}{cl}
 \nbput[nrot=:U,labelsep=0.075cm]{\small{$ \omega_{mut}$} }
\rput(0,-1.8){$\bullet$ Crear $\lambda$ mutantes de $p_1$}
\end{pspicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
&[name=Conjunto]
\begin{pspicture}[shift=-2.5](-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
\psframegray(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
\pstriangle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gris135,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red,linewidth=0.06cm,linearc=0.4](0,-1.56)(5.0,4.2)
%
 \rput(0,1.5){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=azultenue]{p1}{\textcolor{black}{$p_1$}}}
%
 \rput(-1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c1}{\textcolor{black}{$c_1$}}}
 \rput(-0.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c2}{\textcolor{black}{$c_2$}}}
%
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.1,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.4,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.7,-1)
%
 \rput(1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{cl}{\textcolor{black}{$c_\lambda$}}}

\rput(0,-1.8){$\bullet$ Evaluar Padres e Hijos}
\rput(0,-2.2){$\bullet$ Elegir el más apto del conjunto}
\end{pspicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
&[name=EM]
\begin{pspicture}[shift=-2.5](-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
\psframegray(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
%
 \rput(0,0){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=verdetenue]{pnuevo}{\textcolor{black}{\hspace{0.36cm}}}}
%
\rput(0,-1.8){$\bullet$ El individuo elegido}
\rput(0,-2.3){ sustituirá a $p_1$}
\end{pspicture}
\\
\end{psmatrix}
\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, arrows=->, nodesep=4pt,  linearc=0.25, angleB=180, shortput=nab, npos = 0.4,nodesep=2.6cm}
\ncline{Inicio}{Conjunto}
\ncline{Conjunto}{EM}

\caption{\vspace{4.5cm}Esquema $(1+\lambda)$}\label{1maslambda-ilustracion}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**
@Mika: Due to the comments I think you don't believe me. So let me show your the issue in a simple example.

Let us take the following sequence: `a\psframe(0,0)(1,1)b` -- I think you should expect the following output `a"frame"b` whereby the distance between `a` and `b` will be 1cm.

However this is wrong. The frame isn't drawn by TeX. So in the sense of TeX the command `\psframe` has no width and height. To fix this issue the environment `pspicture` is used to reserve the needed space.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

a\psframe(0,0)(1,1)b
\end{document}
```

Comment: @herbert gives me the solution with \vspace{2.5cm} before caption

Comment: @MikaIke: This is a manual adjusting and a quick fix. I think a more elegant solution is my ;-)

Comment: I can´t understand because I was using that \resizebox{8cm}{!}{....} many times since other people here tell me about that insctruction. I think that it doesn´t the reason of the error. Thank you.

Comment: @MikaIke: Please read my updated answer.

Comment: I belive yyou, but I thought that it was possible. The solution is the graphicx package as Herbert answered me in this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181435/how-to-reescale-a-pstricks-image-with-subcaption/181437?noredirect=1#comment419309_181437

Comment: @MikaIke: The trick with `\resizebox` is equal to `pspicture`. The contents is put in an extra box and scaled. :-)